# rexec not found in HP UX

Tags: c, hp-ux

Simple program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret = rexec((char**) 0, "", "", "", 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
$ g++ -o rexec -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED rexec.cpp

rexec.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
rexec.cpp:10:49: error: 'rexec' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Have you try [this](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/configuring-rexec-in-hpux/td-p/5273543)?

Comment: @hmjd Not quite what he's asking about!

Comment: @NicholasWilson, chuckle oops.

Answer (score 0):

> These functions **are not** in POSIX.1-2001.  The rexec() function first
>   appeared in 4.2BSD, and is present on the BSDs, Solaris, and many
>   other systems. The rexec_af() function is more recent, and less
>   widespread.

Source: "man rexec"

Answer (score 0):

```
find /usr/local -type f -print -exec grep rexec {} \; # no rgrep/grep -R on HP-UX
```

There clearly is no rexec function in any header on my HP-UX system.

HP-UX doesn't have it. You'll have to implement it yourself by just doing a `popen` on the `rexec(1)` application, I guess (not too hard). Or, stop using rexec!